# Unity jobs native array cleared data issue

Tags: unity-game-engine, 3d, jobs

[image]
ive been working on generating details and for almost no reason some of the deserts just dont get any details.

```cs
NativeArray<Detail> details = new NativeArray<Detail>(chunk.GetBiome().details, Allocator.Persistent);
        Debug.Log(chunk.GetBiome().id + "'s details length = " + details.Length);
```

right here i pass in the details array to my job.
And this is what it logs
[image: log for first line]

```cs
public GetMeshData(ChunkData chunkData, NativeArray<Vector3> vertices, NativeArray<Vector2> uvs, NativeArray<int> triangles, NativeArray<float> noiseMap, NativeArray<Color> colorMap, NativeArray<TerrainColor> terrainColors,
    NativeArray<Detail> details, NativeList<DetailPlacement> detailPlacements, float detailsChance)
    {
        this.chunkData = chunkData;
        this.meshData = new MeshData(vertices, uvs, triangles, detailPlacements);
        this.noiseMap = noiseMap;
        this.colorMap = colorMap;
        this.terrainColors = terrainColors;
        this.details = details;
        this.detailsChance = detailsChance;
    }
```

This is the constructor for the job where my details array is passed.

```cs
MeshData temporaryMeshData = MeshGeneration.GenerateMesh(chunkData, noiseMap, meshData.triangles, meshData.vertices, meshData.uvs, details, meshData.detailPlacements, detailsChance);
```

These are now used in this method.
Now here’s the weird part. When I log details.length in the method.

```cs
public static MeshData GenerateMesh(ChunkData chunkData, NativeArray<float> heightmap, NativeArray<int> triangles,
    NativeArray<Vector3> vertices, NativeArray<Vector2> uvs, NativeArray<Detail> details, NativeList<DetailPlacement> detailPlacements, float detailChance)
    {
        Debug.Log("detail length sent into mesh method = " + details.Length);
```

It’s now empty
This problem shows up in and off this was just an example of a time where the problem occurred happens with one of 3 deserts usually.

[image]
Update: i tried to make it so all job structs were being processed at the time by making it so that there will only be a job struct for each thread and when one finished it would grab the next one from the ones waiting. This had no effect.

Comment: It's really hard to follow what's happening when you omit code.  Based on your description I would put a debug point on every line that references details in this path, and see when it gets cleared out.  My guess is there must be something happening after your constructor but before the call to GenerateMesh.

Comment: yep i already did that and it got cleared at the exact point you said ill make a github page for it if people need to see more of the code